# Wicked PDF gem generated PDF views are being cached by browsers | Rails 5.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, browser-cache, wicked-pdf

I'm working on a project that has the functionality to export `index` views as PDF. This all works perfectly with the [Wicked PDF](https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf) gem, however, in production, the generated PDFs are cached by browsers and therefore can be out of date. Refreshing a PDF view does fetch latest data, but simply navigating to the PDF view only seems to use the browser-cached document. Is there a way to prevent the PDF view from being cached by browsers?

**Controller**

```
class InvoicesController < ApplicationController
  # GET /invoices
  def index
    @invoices = Invoice.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.pdf do
        render pdf: "Invoices_#{Time.current.strftime("%Y_%m_%d_at_%H_%M")}",
               template:       'invoices/index',
               show_as_html:   params.key?('debug'),
               title:          "Invoices_#{Time.current.strftime("%Y_%m_%d_at_%H_%M")}", # otherwise first page title is used
               orientation:    :landscape,
               margin:         { top:    15,                     # default 10 (mm)
                                 bottom: 15,
                                 left:   15,
                                 right:  45 },
               footer:         { left: "Extracted: #{Time.current.to_formatted_s(:date_at_time)}",
                                 right: "Page [page] of [topage]" }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do by clearing the cache for that page

```
 class InvoicesController < ApplicationController
    before_action :set_cache_headers

      private

      def set_cache_headers
        response.headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache, no-store"
        response.headers["Pragma"] = "no-cache"
        response.headers["Expires"] = Time.now
      end
    end
end
```